# Google Sheets ImportXML - Insert dynamic query if cell is filled

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google Sheets as a scraper for youtube videos. I would like to make the sheet even more dynamic, but it doesn't seem to work.

For example, I would like to write "How to get my baby to sleep" as a search query, therefore I would write this query into H6. If H6 is filled now, I would like to dynamically insert this query into the importXML function.

This is what I've already had, but I can't get this to work.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("https://www.youtube.com"&QUERY(QUERY(UNIQUE(
 IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=**{{dynamicInsertion}}**","//a/@href")),
 "where Col1 contains '/watch?v='"),"limit 50"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("https://www.youtube.com/"&QUERY(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="&H6, "//a/@href"), 
 "where Col1 matches '/channel.+|/watch.+|/user.+|/results.+' 
  order by Col1 desc"))
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("https://www.youtube.com/"&QUERY(UNIQUE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="&H6, "//a/@href")), 
 "where Col1 matches '/channel.+|/watch.+|/user.+|/results.+' 
  order by Col1 desc limit 50"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This seems to work, but I'm getting results twice and also I get to many videos, since there is no limit set.

Answer (score 0):

to scrape beyond the first page of infinite scroll use:

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE(QUERY({
 IMPORTXML("https://www.ecosia.org/videos?q="    &SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "+"), "//a/@href");
 IMPORTXML("https://www.ecosia.org/videos?p=1&q="&SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "+"), "//a/@href");
 IMPORTXML("https://www.ecosia.org/videos?p=2&q="&SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "+"), "//a/@href");
 IMPORTXML("https://www.ecosia.org/videos?p=3&q="&SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "+"), "//a/@href");
 IMPORTXML("https://www.ecosia.org/videos?p=4&q="&SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "+"), "//a/@href");
 IMPORTXML("https://www.ecosia.org/videos?p=5&q="&SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "+"), "//a/@href");
 IMPORTXML("https://www.ecosia.org/videos?p=6&q="&SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "+"), "//a/@href");
 IMPORTXML("https://www.ecosia.org/videos?p=7&q="&SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "+"), "//a/@href");
 IMPORTXML("https://www.ecosia.org/videos?p=8&q="&SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "+"), "//a/@href");
 IMPORTXML("https://www.ecosia.org/videos?p=9&q="&SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "+"), "//a/@href")}, 
 "where Col1 contains 'watch'")), "limit 50", 0)
```

[image: 0]